# How to change woocommerce class using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a category with "woocommerce columns-3" class and I want to change it to "woocommerce columns-4". How can I do it using javascript?

I've tried this code without sucess:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById("main").classList.add('woocommerce columns-4');
document.getElementById("main").classList.remove('woocommerce columns-3');
</script>
```

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvg9D.png)

Comment: Did you mean that classes of "main" is ["woocommerce", "columns-4"]  and you want to change it to ["woocommerce", "columns-3"]. If so, that is not hard, just call remove("columns-4") and then calls add("columns-3").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must target the correct element to make it work. In your code you are trying to target an element with the id main.

I would recommend using `document.querySelector()`
So your code would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// select element        
var ourElement=document.querySelector(".elementor-widget-container .woocommerce.columns-3");
ourElement.classList.remove('columns-3');
ourElement.classList.add('columns-4');
</script>
```